# Splitting an image in batches of tiles

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a large image and I am extracting and processing tiles in batches of a given size. A tile is normally a 256x256 region and batches are normally a power of 2.

In the below example the number of tiles per cols is 3 and the number of tiles per rows is 5, and I want batches of 3.

[image: Tiling large image]

Legend: Yellow rectangle = tile, Red rectangle = batch of tiles, Blue rectangle = full image

Is my code Pythonic enough, can I get extra speed?

```
import numpy as np
batch_size = 3

input_raster = ... numpy array of shape (3,image_width,image_height)
output_raster = ...numpy array of shape (3,image_width,image_height)    
nb_tiles_per_cols = 3
nb_tiles_per_rows = 5

total = nb_tiles_per_cols * nb_tiles_per_rows
remaining = total
    
for i in range(0,total,batch_size):
    size = min(remaining,batch_size)
    batch_input = np.ndarray((size,256,256,1))
    for j in range(0,size):
        # handle index i+j
        indexRC = i+j
        col = indexRC % nb_tiles_per_cols
        row = indexRC // nb_tiles_per_cols
        # read tile from input raster of shape (3,256*nb_tiles_per_rows,256*nb_tiles_per_cols)
        img = input_raster[:,row*256:(row+1)*256,col*256:(col+1)*256]
        # process img to get input_image
        ...
        batch_input[j] = input_image
    # inference.predict return an array of shape (size,256,256,1)
    predictions = inference.predict(batch_input)
            
    for j in range(0,size):
        # handle index i+j
        indexRC = i+j
        col = indexRC % nb_tiles_per_cols
        row = indexRC // nb_tiles_per_cols

        output_raster[row*256:(row+1)*256,col*256:(col+1)*256] = predictions[j]
                    
        remaining -= size
```

Comment: Rather than using `lang-python` to get syntax highlighting you can add the Python tag to enable it.

Comment: _the number of tiles per cols is 3_ - are you sure? Isn't that the number of columns per tile?

Comment: If you look at the example image, there are 3 tiles vertically and 5 tiles horizontally. The full image is made of 15 tiles. So the number of tiles in a column is 3. A tile is a yellow rectangle.

Comment: Oh. A "legend" such as "yellow is a tile; red is a batch" would help.